# Entity Framework (model-first) deleting multiple entries with same attribute

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

My question is simple, I have a table in Entity Framework, I want to delete all entries (rows) in that table that have the same attribute TemplateID (foreign key).

I have tried multiple methods, all giving me internal error 500:

**Method1:**

```
db.Item2.RemoveRange(db.Item2.Where(x => x.TemplateID == idT));
db.SaveChanges();
```

getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"Attaching an entity of type \u0027CustomTemplates.Models2.CustomTemplate\u0027 failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the \u0027Attach\u0027 method or setting the state of an entity to \u0027Unchanged\u0027 or \u0027Modified\u0027 if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the \u0027Add\u0027 method or the \u0027Added\u0027 entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to \u0027Unchanged\u0027 or \u0027Modified\u0027 as appropriate.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyRootForAdd(Boolean doAttach, String entitySetName, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityEntry existingEntry, EntitySet\u0026 entitySet, Boolean\u0026 isNoOperation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.\u003c\u003ec__DisplayClassa.\u003cAttach\u003eb__9()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value)\r\n   at CustomTemplates.WebService1.DeleteTemplate(String itemid) in C:\\Users\\A.J\\source\\repos\\CustomTemplates\\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 243","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

**Method2:**

```
var itemD = new Item2() { TemplateID = idT };
using (TestEntities db = new TestEntities())
        {
           db.Item2.Remove(itemD);
           db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity, EntitySet expectedEntitySet)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.RemoveRange(IEnumerable entities)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.RemoveRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)\r\n   at CustomTemplates.WebService1.DeleteTemplate(String itemid) in C:\\Users\\A.J\\source\\repos\\CustomTemplates\\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 242","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

**Method3:**

replacing

```
var itemD = new Item2() { TemplateID = idT };
```

with

```
IList<Item2> itemD = new List<Item2>() {

            new Item2() { TemplateID = idT}

        };
```

and remove with removerange

getting error:

```
{"Message":"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity, EntitySet expectedEntitySet)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Remove(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Remove(TEntity entity)\r\n   at CustomTemplates.WebService1.DeleteTemplate(String itemid) in C:\\Users\\A.J\\source\\repos\\CustomTemplates\\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 242","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

**Method 4:**

```
var itemtD = db.Item2
                .Where(i => i.TemplateID == idT);

            foreach (Item2 ite in itemtD)
            {
                db.Item2.Remove(ite);
                //db.Item2.DeleteObject(ite);

            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

here for some reason DeleteObject gives

```
Error   CS1061  'DbSet<Item2>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Item2>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

simple remove gives the following error:

```
{"Message":"Attaching an entity of type \u0027CustomTemplates.Models2.CustomTemplate\u0027 failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the \u0027Attach\u0027 method or setting the state of an entity to \u0027Unchanged\u0027 or \u0027Modified\u0027 if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the \u0027Add\u0027 method or the \u0027Added\u0027 entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to \u0027Unchanged\u0027 or \u0027Modified\u0027 as appropriate.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyRootForAdd(Boolean doAttach, String entitySetName, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityEntry existingEntry, EntitySet\u0026 entitySet, Boolean\u0026 isNoOperation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.\u003c\u003ec__DisplayClassa.\u003cAttach\u003eb__9()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value)\r\n   at CustomTemplates.WebService1.DeleteTemplate(String itemid) in C:\\Users\\A.J\\source\\repos\\CustomTemplates\\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 243","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

I don't know what else to try, and what exactly is the problem. deleting a single entry works perfectly fine.

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Are you sure Item2 entity that you want to delete isn't referenced on another table?

Comment: Well I'm fairly certain, although now that you brought that up, I used model first, and EF made the context as such : public virtual DbSet<Item2> Item2 { get; set; }, maybe that might cause it? it uses the same name for the context. Anyway the solution of @Slava Utesinov works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/) library:

```
db.Item2.Where(x => x.TemplateID == idT).Delete();
```